# Show that $\textbf{A}\cdot\nabla G=0$ for given $G$ and $\bf{A}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, solution-verification

I have solved

$$yu_x+u_y=u^2$$

using $x=-\frac{s^2}{2},\,y=s>0,\,u=1$ and obtained the solution

$$u(x,y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{y^2}{2}-x}+1-y}$$

Now I am trying to show $\textbf{A}\cdot\nabla G=0$ where

$$G(x,y,u)=\sqrt{\frac{y^2}{2}-x}+1-y-\dfrac{1}{u}=0, \qquad\textbf{A}=(y,1,u^2)$$

Therefore, as

$$\nabla G = \left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{y^2}{2}-x\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}+\dfrac{u_x}{u^2},\,\frac{y}{2}\left(\frac{y^2}{2}-x\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}-1+\dfrac{u_y}{u^2},\,\frac{1}{u^2}\right)$$

I find that

\begin{align}
\textbf{A}\cdot{\nabla}G &= -\frac{y}{2}\left(\frac{y^2}{2}-x\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}+y\dfrac{u_x}{u^2}+\frac{y}{2}\left(\frac{y^2}{2}-x\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}-1+\dfrac{u_y}{u^2}+1 \\
&= y\frac{u_x}{u^2}+\frac{u_y}{u^2} \\
&= 1
\end{align}

This should be equal to zero though so where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gradient of $G(x,y,u)$ (note that $u$ is a free variable) should be
$$\nabla G(x,y,u)=\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{y^2}{2}-x\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}},\,\frac{y}{2}\left(\frac{y^2}{2}-x\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}-1,\,\frac{1}{u^2}\right)$$
and then we find
$$\textbf{A}\cdot{\nabla}G=-\frac{y}{2}\left(\frac{y^2}{2}-x\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}+\frac{y}{2}\left(\frac{y^2}{2}-x\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}-1+1=0.$$
I try to put it in other words. Let $u=h(x,y)$ be any solution of $yu_x+u_y=u^2$ and define $G(x,y,u)=\frac{1}{h(x,y)}-\frac{1}{u}$. Then
$$\nabla G(x,y,u)=\left(-\frac{h_x}{h^2},-\frac{h_y}{h^2},\frac{1}{u^2}\right)$$
and
$$\textbf{A}\cdot{\nabla}G=(y,1,u^2)\cdot
\left(-\frac{h_x}{h^2},-\frac{h_y}{h^2},\frac{1}{u^2}\right)=-\frac{yh_x}{h^2}-\frac{h_y}{h^2}+1=0.$$
Therefore the verification of $\textbf{A}\cdot{\nabla}G=0$ can be done without solving $yu_x+u_y=u^2$ explicitly.

Comment: Does $u$ become a free variable when we define the new implicit function $G$ because this is something I was not sure about? And why does it become a free variable as is it not intrinsically defined as a function of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: @awgya $F(x,y):=G(x,y,u(x,y))$ is a function of two variables. The gradient $\nabla F$ has two components $F_x$ and $F_y$. These are the first two components of your $\nabla G$.

Comment: Apologies, but I am rather confused. I still do not understand why $u$ is a free variable and what this actually means.

Comment: How would its gradient be in $\mathbb{R}^2$? for $G(x,y,u(x,y))$ we have $\nabla=\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x},\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y},\dfrac{\partial}{\partial u}\right)$.

Comment: If you apply $\nabla=\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x},\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y},\dfrac{\partial}{\partial u}\right)$ then you first take the gradient of $G$ with $u$ free variable and then you put $u=u(x,y)$. In this case you should not derive $G(x,y,u(x,y))$ as a composite function (as you did).